# How do I make a list of the two last letters in every word in a text using slice?

Tags: python

I am new to Python, and I'm trying to solve a task.

I have a very long text, let's call it "file". I want to make a list of the two last letters of every word in this text. 
This is what I have, and what I thought would work:

```
list=[i[-2:] for i in file]

print(list)
```

But instead, my list consists of EVERY character in the text, and not only the last two letters of every word.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: if `file` a file or a string?

Comment: `[i[-2:] for line in file for i in line.split()]` should do it, unless there's some punctuation to consider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `file` isn't a file, but a string.

```
>>> file = "abc\ndef"
>>> [i[-2:] for i in file]
['a', 'b', 'c', '\n', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Since `file` is a string, `for i in file` iterates over every character of the string. `list` is then the two last characters of every character : it's basically every character.

You need to iterate over each line of the file, and iterate again over each word of each line. To do so, you could use `line.split()`.

Here's an example:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    word_endings = [w[-2:] for line in f for w in line.split()]

print(word_endings)
# ['bc', 'ef', 'hi', 'lm']
```

BTW, you should avoid overwriting already defined Python variables (e.g. `list`).

Answer (score 2):

your `file` variable is probably the buffer itself, not the file handle. But anyway, you need some splitting.

If `f` is a file handle, you could iterate on the lines, split them using `str.split`, and take the 2 last chars.

```
result = [w[-2:] for line in f for w in line.split()]
```

if `f` is a buffer, you don't need 2 loops:

```
result = [w[-2:] for w in f.split()]
```

This approach is too simplistic when there are punctuation marks in your text. In that case, it's better to split using `re.split`, like below:

```
import re

f = """Hello, I'm John.
How are you ?""".splitlines() # kind of emulate a file handle iterator


result = [w[-2:] for line in f for w in re.split("\W+",line) if w]

print(result)
```

result:

```
['lo', 'I', 'm', 'hn', 'ow', 're', 'ou']
```

that approach also works with simple cases, of course. Note the filtering of some parasite empty tokens (`if w`) that doesn't happen with `str.split` without argument. Well, we can live with that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to split your string so that the text can be made a list of words.

```
very_long_text = "consists EVERY character in the text, and not only the last two letters of every word."
print ([line[-2:] for line in very_long_text.split(" ")])
```

your program:

```
input_list=[i[-2:] for i in file.split(" ")]
print(input_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your text file was:

```
this is my first line
a second line 
third line
```

The following script would read each line, split it into a list of words and add the endings for each into the list `word_endings`:

```
word_endings = []

with open('input.txt') as f_input:
    for line in f_input:
        word_endings.extend([word[-2:] for word in line.split()])

print(word_endings)
```

This would give you:

```
['is', 'is', 'my', 'st', 'ne', 'a', 'nd', 'ne', 'rd', 'ne']
```